# Can we say "Floor 10"?

Tags: phrase-usage, numbers

Is it acceptable to say:

> "Floor 10"?

Or should we always say:

> "the 10th Floor"?

Comment: It's fine. But don't say *"floor ground"*.

Answer (score 6):

It is acceptable to say or write "Floor 10"; in the U. S., it is commonly used that way in writing an address in business correspondence and on envelopes for mailing. Writing "the 10th Floor" is also acceptable.

Comment: It may be acceptable, but I would hardly agree that it is common ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Floor+10%2C+10th+Floor&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)). I personally never have seen this usage on written correspondence (U.S.)  This does contrast with "Room 10" or "Suite 10," both of which would be standard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is acceptable to say:

> "Floor 10".

We may not always say:

> "the 10th Floor".

Answer (score 2):

I'm agreeing with the other answers that say "Yes".  Context can also affect the likely answer.

If I am near the swimming pool on the ground floor, and I ask where the gift shop is, people are probably more likely to say "the second floor".

If I am in an elevator, and somebody asks me which floor I'm going to, I am more likely to say "Floor two" (or perhaps just "two").

Both are acceptable in either case.  I suppose that the difference is in expectations.  If there is a clear reason why a person would expect a floor number, "floor two" would seem more natural/common.  If a person isn't necessarily expecting a reference to a floor, then "the second floor" just feels more natural/common.  (This may just be my own opinion, rather than a universal rule that most people would be likely to agree with.)